# PhpStorm code coverage with remote Xdebug - can't connect (Xdebug 2.5.5)

Tags: debugging, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a problem which I've been facing for 2 days. I've already configured my PHPUnit in PhpStorm, made code coverage save to log folders. I want to connect with Xdebug so I can make code coverage visible in my IDE. The problem is, I can't connect to remote Xdebug. I'm having a message: "Connection with 'Xdebug 2.5.5' was not established."

Guy from other team helped me to configure Xdebug as they have it configured for other project. I cloned this project, set it up and working, configured everything as he has it configured. And still cannot connect.

Port: 9000 (also got proxy for 9001-9005).
Windows firewall is off, ports are unlocked
IDE key is set on.
Tried with `-dxdebug.remote_host` command - still nothing
Set up our proxy host IP for Xdebug - still nothing.

Anyone has other idea?

Comment: *"The problem is, I can't connect to remote Xdebug..."* The problem is -- IDE does NOT connect to Xdebug -- it's Xdebug connects to IDE. Check the manual to get the basics: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote. Also -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm . With your info so far it's not possible to say what you are doing wrong or even what your setup is to start with.

Comment: I can establish connection via Proxy server on port 9001. The problem is I can't make Run test with debug. Even if my session have started. I realized I have these options set off:

xdebug.profiler_enable 
xdebug.remote_connect_back
xdebug.idekey

Comment: *" I realized I have these options set off:"* So is it working now? *"I can establish connection via Proxy server on port 9001"* I'm not using DBGp proxy myself so cannot suggest how such setup will work.